# Do CloudStack and Hyper-V get along?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, cloud

Here is the deal, I need to hook up my Hyper-V environment to my HostBill environment so customers can restart, shut-down and install new virtual machines. Since HostBill doesn't have a Hyper-V application, I decided to use CloudStack as a proxy. However, I only need CloudStack to pass on commands and to stay out of the storage situation.

Currently the Hyper-V environment is just a bunch of hosts who all have their virtual machines on the same share on a different server. It isn't a very traditional Hyper-V set-up, but it does the trick and works like a charm.

Is it possible to use CloudStack to pass on commands to the Hyper-V hosts and to make new virtual machines?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a complex stack for just a few actions on virtual machines. I would recommend Cloudstack only, as it can do all your requirements:

> restart, shut-down and install new virtual machines

Hyper-v support in Cloudstack is present but not the most developed virtualization environment. It will do the basic tasks however.

For billing and customer management, you can also look into http://www.fogpanel.com/ or http://www.amysta.com/